# NHibernate custom Dialect

Tags: nhibernate, dialect

I am dealing with a legacy database, and I am writing a custom driver and dialect to access the data with NHibernate.
I need to suppress the aliases in the generated sql , so I think I should override the genericDialect, right?
is there any tutorial on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is such a rare thing that I don't think you are going to find any tutorials on this subject. Your just going to need to download the source and dig in:

Current version of the source: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core

Previous versions: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/

You may want to have a look at the following method:

```
NHibernate.Dialect.ExtractColumnOrAliasNames()
```

Find the usages of that method to see how other dialects are using it.

Also try searching for the word 'alias' and look particularly for usages of that word in the NHibernate.Dialect namespace. Even then, it's probably going to take quite a bit of investigation of the code to find your answer.

If you do find manage to suppress the aliases, be sure to post a follow up, create a blog entry, etc. to share your findings as I for one would be quite interested.

Comment: All previous versions are available as tags in the github repository.